# Can't Find nullpointer please assist

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This is the class i gain a null pointer from it points to line 65.

```
 public class searchlist extends ListActivity 
  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new loadSomeStuff().execute();
}

public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]>
{
  ProgressDialog dialog;

  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
     dialog = new ProgressDialog(searchlist.this); 
     dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     dialog.setMax(100);
     dialog.show();
  }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(int i =0; i<20; i++)
        {
          publishProgress(5);
          try
          {
          Thread.sleep(80);
          } catch(InterruptedException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        int loops = search_page.returnlooped();
        int[] teacup = search_page.returnNumArray();
        sqlStuff searching = new sqlStuff(searchlist.this);
        String[] IDSysNames = searching.getIDSysName();
        searching.close();

        String[] resultList = new String[loops];
        for(int i=0; i < loops; i++ )
        {
            if(IDSysNames[teacup[i]] != null)
            {

            resultList[i].equals(IDSysNames[teacup[i]]);    //Line 65 

            }
        }
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(searchlist.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultList));
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress)
    {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
    }
}
```

This is the getIDSysname class used by the class above.

```
 public String[] getIDSysName()
{
    String[] result = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_SYSNAME};
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.d("SqlDStuff", "Cursor count: "+c.getCount());
        int iSysName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSNAME);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result[i] = c.getString(iSysName);
            i++;

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   

    }

    return result;
}
```

If anything else is needed please ask in the comments because this is frustrating me at the moment. Thank you

Comment: Attach a debugger and "break on exceptions". Inspect the current values/expressions to find out what is `null`. Assistance provided.

Comment: i'll give it a go now

Comment: wow didn't know you could do that but i've found out all my other variables are fine but all of the result array is null and isnt taking up its new values.

Comment: Now, why are they null? :D Remember that array items are all *initialized to the default value* of the given type - and the default value of all reference types is `null`. However, it still doesn't make sense to do the equals test for an item that hasn't been previously set .. (`resultList[i].equals(..)` <- but not set to anything. I think perhaps using `ArrayList<String> resultList ..` and `resultList.add` would be more useful.)

Comment: i've ran through the code and found that after it finishes the for loop none of the values are null. But the null pointer is still coming up. Also it shows my db class as a variable even tho i've closed it before the loop.

Comment: Isn't the exception coming from *inside* the loop?

Comment: that is where it is pointing but neither values in the loop are null when the loop finishes

Comment: If any exception is thrown then all further code execution (until a catch/finally) is not performed - that's just the rules. Make sure you are looking at the `resultList` variable and not the `searchList` variable. The `resultList` variable will *never* have non-null elements with the above code because no index was ever assigned a (non-default) value.

Comment: i looked at the logcat again and it is also pointing at where the package is declared so line 1 strange

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated an array of strings:

```
String[] resultList = new String[loops];
for (int i=0; i < loops; i++ ) {
    if (IDSysNames[teacup[i]] != null) {
        resultList[i].equals(IDSysNames[teacup[i]]);    //Line 65
```

There aren't any strings in it upon which to call `equals`.

Comment: what do you mean there arent any they are added above          String[] IDSysNames = searching.getIDSysName();

Comment: @user1844616 Where? There's no code between declaring `resultList` and calling `equals` on the contents of `resultList`. `resultList` is an array of nulls. `IDSysNames` is irrelevant; the nulls are in `resultList`.

Comment: @user1844616 Plus what's the point of calling `equals` when the results are immediately discarded?

Comment: resultList[i].equals(IDSysNames[teacup[i]]);                            I Thought this made the resultlist array values equal whatever the IDSysNames{teacup[i]] is.

Comment: @user1844616 No, you're calling `equals` on the contents of `resultList[i]`, just like the code says. If you want to *assign* a value, use `=`, the assignment operator: `resultList[i] = IDSysNames[teacup[i]]`

Comment: it is still giving me null point when i exchange.equals for = any other ideas??

Comment: @user1844616 Then either IDSysNames is null, or teacup is null, or the error occurs somewhere else. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
   dialog.dismiss();
```

you can not call dismiss on `doInBackground()`. Every method pertinent to the UI Thread has to be called on the UI Thread.

try with:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, but seems unrelated to the NPE on line 65, though.

Comment: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(searchlist.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultList))

Answer (score 0):

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(searchlist.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultList));

I had to move this method to the onCreate(); and i had to retrun the resultList value via a method called onPostExecute.

Turns out the log cat was making up the null pointer don't know why . Thanks guys but i got it now.